SonarQube nullability check works better with Apache's method than with mine?
I'm trying to understand the following behaviour of SonarQube, which gets in the way of me using my own methods.
Apache declares this function :
package org.apache.commons.lang3;

public class StringUtils {
    ...
    public static boolean isEmpty(final CharSequence cs) {
        return cs == null || cs.length() == 0;
    }
}

I have my own StringUtil class which declares the exact same function :
package common.utils;

public final class StringUtil {
    private StringUtil() {}
    
    ...
    public static boolean isEmpty(final CharSequence cs) {
        return cs == null || cs.length() == 0;
    }
}

They are identical so I expect Sonarqube's code analysis to react to both in the same way.
...And yet, then when I do this :
public static void foobar(final String s) {
     if(StringUtil.isEmpty(s)) {
        return;
     }
     s.doSomething(); // <-- SonarQube says that s can be null, but only with my method.
}

SonarQube complains about s potentially null and adds a "severe" code smell to my build process, BUT only when it's my function. When it's Apache's function then SonarQube understands that s cannot be null and stops complaining (no code smell report).
what am I doing wrong?
